# HashSet is adding duplicate Strings

Tags: java, set, hashset

**EDIT**
im sorry, i had a typo somewhere, which i couldnt find when i re-read it about 500 times -.-
im sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for your input.

My problem is, that i somehow have `"ghost"-elements` in a `HashSet`.

I have **2** `HashSets` of `Strings` (lets call them **A** and **B**) which are filled in a loop.

After that, I want to compare them and get some strange results:

```
A.size() -> 54201
B.size() -> 54201
```

Then, I do some operations like remove and retain on my sets (all operations are done with copies of the original sets):

```
A.removeAll(B).size() -> 48
B.removeAll(A).size() -> 0
```

This is where I started wondering. If there are no duplicates and the sets are the same size, how can there differences not be the same size?

```
A.retainAll(B).size() -> 54201
B.retainAll(A).size() -> 54201
```

It seems like they have the same elements and size, but `A` has `48` elements more(?!?)

```
A.equals(B) -> false
```

When I converted them into Arrays, this happened:

```
Object[] A_array = A.toArray()
Object[] B_array = B.toArray()

A_array.length -> 54249 // here is my difference of 48 elements
B_array.length -> 54201
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?
Why are there `48` elements in the array which are appearently not in the set?

Thanks for your help, I really am out of ideas.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your comments, i will try to state some more details and code. As for an MVCE, i will try to get one, but i am not sure if it will be possible.

The case is, i am downloading emails via IMAP and then read the message-ids from the header. I do this for 2 accounts and then i want to compare if they have the same messages.

So, heres the code (since i have to work with jsps, its java 1.6):

```
Set<String> srcMsgIds = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> dstMsgIds = new HashSet<String>();

Message[] srcMsgs = imap.searchInAllFolder(srcEmail); // download javax.mail.Message
for(Message m : srcMsgs) {
    IMAPMessage msg = (IMAPMessage) m;
    String rfc822msgid = msg.getMessageID();
    srcMsgIds.add(rfc822msgid.toLowerCase());
}

Message[] dstMsgs = imap.searchInAllFolder(destEmail);  // download javax.mail.Message
for(Message m : dstMsgs) {
    IMAPMessage msg = (IMAPMessage) m;
    String rfc822msgid = msg.getMessageID();
    dstMsgIds.add(rfc822msgid.toLowerCase());
}

int srcCount = new HashSet<String>(dstMsgIds).size(); // 54201
int dstCount = new HashSet<String>(dstMsgIds).size(); // 54201

Set<String> intersectionSrcDst = new HashSet<String>(srcMsgIds); // both in src and dst
intersectionSrcDst.retainAll(dstMsgIds);
int intersection1Count = intersectionSrcDst.size(); // 54201

Set<String> intersectionDstSrc = new HashSet<String>(dstMsgIds);
intersectionDstSrc.retainAll(srcMsgIds);
int intersection2Count = intersectionDstSrc.size(); // 54201

Set<String> srcNotDst = new HashSet<String>(srcMsgIds);
srcNotDst.removeAll(dstMsgIds);
int diff1Count = srcNotDst.size(); // 48

Set<String> dstNotSrc = new HashSet<String>(dstMsgIds);
dstNotSrc.removeAll(srcMsgIds);
int diff2Count = dstNotSrc.size(); // 0

Object[] srcArray = srcMsgIds.toArray();
Object[] dstArray = dstMsgIds.toArray();
int srcArrayLength = srcArray.length; // 54249
int dstArrayLength = dstArray.length; // 54201
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you provide [mcve] that we can just execute and see the problem...? Also, please format your code properly.

Comment: why you working with copies by the way?

Comment: could you include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does show the problem, otherwise the answer will be `not possible`, or it´s unclear. But a hint maybe. did you override `hashCode`, if `A` and `B` do contain your own classes, properly?

Comment: What you have written above is not accurate.

Comment: Yes.  That is the most likely explanation.  One or more of the facts / assumptions in your problem description is probably incorrect.  But we can't tell you which unless you provide an MCVE.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy The OP said these are `HashSets of Strings`.

Comment: @Eran oh it´s in the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course, it was a typo, and i (and none of my colleagues) could find it until now...

im sorry, thanks for your in

Answer (score 0):

```
How did you fill the sets ?
I try a very small piece of code without having these ghost effects.

HashSet<String> A = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> B = new HashSet<String>();
    A.add("dog"); B.add("dog"); 
    A.add("cat"); B.add("cat"); 
    A.add("mouse"); B.add("mouse"); 
    A.add("dog"); B.add("dog"); 

    System.out.println("A is: " + A);
    System.out.println("B is: " + B);

   // A.removeAll(B); System.out.println("A size is: " + A.size()); 
   // A size is: 0
   // B.removeAll(A); System.out.println("B size is: " + B.size()); 
   // B size is: 0

// A.retainAll(B);  System.out.println("A size after retain is: "+A.size());
// A size after retain is: 3
// B.retainAll(A);  System.out.println("B size after retain is: "+B.size()); // B size after retain is: 3
   System.out.println("A == B ? :" + A.equals(B)); // A == B ? :true
```